# Generate a data range for every consecutive hour in a specified time interval in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a set of intervals for each hour during a predefined set of dates using Pandas. I have used:

```
import pandas as pd

print pd.date_range(start='2013-04-01', end='2013-04-30', freq='1H')

DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-01 01:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 02:00:00', '2013-04-01 03:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 04:00:00', '2013-04-01 05:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 06:00:00', '2013-04-01 07:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 08:00:00', '2013-04-01 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2013-04-29 15:00:00', '2013-04-29 16:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 17:00:00', '2013-04-29 18:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 19:00:00', '2013-04-29 20:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 21:00:00', '2013-04-29 22:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 23:00:00', '2013-04-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=697, freq='H')
```

However, it generates the interval for every other hour, i.e., [0-1], [2-3], [4-5], ... However, What I need is a partition like [0-1], [1-2], [2-3], ... How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

**Desired output:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-01 01:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 01:00:00', '2013-04-01 02:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 02:00:00', '2013-04-01 03:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 03:00:00', '2013-04-01 04:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 04:00:00', '2013-04-01 05:00:00',
               ...
               '2013-04-29 19:00:00', '2013-04-29 20:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 20:00:00', '2013-04-29 21:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 21:00:00', '2013-04-29 22:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 22:00:00', '2013-04-29 23:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 23:00:00', '2013-04-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=697, freq='H')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [2249]: d = pd.date_range(start='2013-04-01', end='2013-04-30', freq='H')

In [2250]: pd.DatetimeIndex([v for p in zip(d, d[1:]) for v in p])
Out[2250]:
DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-01 01:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 01:00:00', '2013-04-01 02:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 02:00:00', '2013-04-01 03:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 03:00:00', '2013-04-01 04:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 04:00:00', '2013-04-01 05:00:00',
               ...
               '2013-04-29 19:00:00', '2013-04-29 20:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 20:00:00', '2013-04-29 21:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 21:00:00', '2013-04-29 22:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 22:00:00', '2013-04-29 23:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 23:00:00', '2013-04-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1392, freq=None)
```

Or,

```
In [2252]: pd.DatetimeIndex(itertools.chain(*zip(d, d[1:])))
Out[2252]:
DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-01 01:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 01:00:00', '2013-04-01 02:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 02:00:00', '2013-04-01 03:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 03:00:00', '2013-04-01 04:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 04:00:00', '2013-04-01 05:00:00',
               ...
               '2013-04-29 19:00:00', '2013-04-29 20:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 20:00:00', '2013-04-29 21:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 21:00:00', '2013-04-29 22:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 22:00:00', '2013-04-29 23:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 23:00:00', '2013-04-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1392, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner, doing it directly:

```
In [237]: pd.date_range(start='2013-04-01', end='2013-04-30', freq='0.5H1U').round('1H')
Out[237]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01 00:00:00', '2013-04-01 01:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 01:00:00', '2013-04-01 02:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 02:00:00', '2013-04-01 03:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 03:00:00', '2013-04-01 04:00:00',
               '2013-04-01 04:00:00', '2013-04-01 05:00:00',
               ...
               '2013-04-29 19:00:00', '2013-04-29 20:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 20:00:00', '2013-04-29 21:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 21:00:00', '2013-04-29 22:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 22:00:00', '2013-04-29 23:00:00',
               '2013-04-29 23:00:00', '2013-04-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1392, freq=None)
```

I use a frequency of half an hour, plus one millisecond, so that the rounding always falls on the "right side".

Comment: Neat use of `freq` and `round`!